# HTTP GET request to get binary content of an XML file

Tags: xml, http, binary, get, format

I'm trying to get the binary content of an XML file through HTTP but the server just want to give me kind of interpreted format (wich removes \r for every \r\n).

My HTTP GET request is simple : "GET http://%s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n"

It works for extention except .xml. And if I change the .xml in .notxml, it works.

So, I'm looking for a way to the binary content without any change in the file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: It's a linux server (Apache 2.2.17), I have access to a CPanel. And I can just add MIME-Type (type and extention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by my FTP Client (FileZilla). If I transfer .nxml and rename in .xml by FTP, the file is OK.
Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the server.  When you ask it for an XML file it looks in a table that maps extensions to Mime-Types. In the default case, the mime-type for XML is either `text/xml` or `application/xml`, both of which are considered text formats and subject to line-ending translation.  To get a binary stream for XML you have to find a way to force the server to treat it as binary instead of text. This means changing the server configuration or using a different extension that is treated as binary.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost definitely a Mime-Type issue. If you're using IIS I would suggest checking out:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx

Comment: @Maladrain you want to just remove the MIME-Type for the "Xml" extension all together. That's why ".notxml" is working correctly, there is no MIME-Type mapping.

Comment: I can't remove "default" MIME-Types on the server. I can just add new one.

Comment: @Malandrain just change the ".xml" content type from "text/xml" to "text/plain". That should serve the same function as removing it.

Comment: @Malandraion I'm sorry, the content-type should be "application/binary" not "plain/text".

Comment: I tried : add new MIME-Type application/binary for xml and the get request with "Content-Type: application/binary" or "Accept: application/binary". And same get requests without the new MIME-Type. No success :(